# iOS: Registering for email attachments - specifically plist

Tags: ios, email, email-attachments

I'm trying to register my app to receive plist attachments but I am not sure of what "type" I should be putting in the info.plist - for example a PDF would be com.Adobe.pdf.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

com.apple.property-list

mdls FTW!